# Appinstaller package full name does not match

Tags: appx, msix, appinstaller

I have created and msix package and an appinstaller for my application so I can have it auto  update.
When I run the appinstaller (with Add-AppxPackage -Appinstaller) I get the message:

`Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x8008020C, The .appinstaller file is invalid. The .appinstaller file is invalid. The package full name returned from the AppxManifest (95c00d63-12ab-4d97-b385-0a13d8e0ab2a_0.6.8.0_neutral__dvqeabx3zpwwy) does not match the name generated from the AppInstaller (95c00d63-12ab-4d97-b385-0a13d8e0ab2a_0.6.8.0_neutral_~_dvqeabx3zpwwy). Please ensure that the package attributes specified in the .appinstaller file match the package attributes referenced in https://application-downloads.azurewebsites.net/staging/WriteInStoneInstaller_0.6.8.0_AnyCPU_Staging.msix.`

The only difference I can see is the tilde between the two underscores. While searching for this online I saw people with package full name containing tilde and without. What is this symbol doing there? What does it denote? How can I specify/change/remove it? I just want the package to install without any errors.